# LTspice, modeling line driver with propagation delay (LH0063)

Tags: ltspice, delay, modeling, propagation

### **Question**

I'm trying to make a component model for the **LH0063** single ended line driver in LTspice... **The propagation delay is the dominant parameter for the frequency response but I'm having a hard time modeling it.**

I'm using the **'Universalopamp2'** component as a voltage follower... I see there are different levels(versions) to this component. **Is there a way I can configure this model's parameters to simulate the propagation delay?**

### **About the part**

from the datasheet:

- Bandwidth: 100MHz
- SlewRate:  6000V/us

From bench testing, the Slewrate is real but the Bandwidth is not... The propagation delay attenuates the signal. The part has a propagation delay of **~5ns** .

- An input **square-wave** signal of 25MHz(Tp=40ns), will be shifted
  by 5ns (45degress phase shift).
- An input **sine-wave** signal of 25MHz(Tp=40ns), will be shifted
  45degress and will be **attenuated by -3db**.

Looks like this on the bench:

[image: Looks like this on the bench.]

Datasheet frequency response:

[image]

### **LTspice Model attempt**

I tried to introduce the prop-delay using a transmission line (**tline**). The problem is tline also limits the edge rate, rather than just causing a delay:

[image]

Here is the simple versions I made (don't care about Bandwidth):
[image]

This I my attempt using tline to introduce the delay, mediocre results.

[image]

Comment: Doesn't LTSpice have a thing called an analogue delay macro (as per micro-cap)?

Comment: Set your maximum timestep in the `.tran` statement to something like `1p`.  You can also try the `delay` or `absdelay` functions with a B-source, but I think you'll have the same problem.  See the "B. Arbitrary Behavioral Voltage or Current Sources" section of the LTspice help for syntax of those functions.

Comment: The BV source with the delay() function does NOT work for AC analysis.

Comment: @Tony  #fakenews.  Can you show an example of it not working?  Or clarify what specifically doesn't work?  Because I can show the opposite.  My group delays match.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihrRZ.png

Comment: Use `level.3b` with appropriate settings and you should get a built-in analog delay, which may be better than the `tline` due to the continuous nature of the tie response. [Here's a quick test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/isQoz.png).

Comment: @Andyaka  It does not, explicitly.  But I looked at the subcircuit for `DELAY.MAC` in MicroCap and it uses a transmission line too but adds VCVS (E-source) buffers at the input and output to isolate the tline's other, likely unwanted, effects.

Comment: I spent the afternoon messing with level.3b... Hard to figure the right combination of GBW, phase margin and slew that produce the right results. The 'delay' is a function a of all 3 of theses.

Comment: You gave no feedback on my suggestion of universally reducing the maximum timestep, so I'll assume you don't like it because it slows the simulation down and the user of your subcircuit needs to know to reduce it.  One way around that is by forcing a timestep reduction based on the signal slew.  You can use `tripdv` and `tripdt` parameters of a B-source to do this.  You can actually still use the tline for your signal path (if you prefer; you still haven't explained why) and throw the B-source off to the side, since its sole purpose would be to force the timesteps for the rest of the circuit.

Comment: [Screenshot of what I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0uYM.png).  Adding the tripdv/tripdt to the B-source also fixes the slew (i.e. the timestep error) on the tline path.  V(out) and V(out2) are right on top of each other.  Also, [here's a reference for those parameters](https://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=B_sources_(common_examples)).

Comment: BV(delay) does work in AC!... I heard otherwise and believed it. Reducing the step size fixes the problem! I saw the suggestion but assumed it was not the problem because other hard edges were being simulated correctly... I'm still working on this, should have a concise solution by the end of the day.

Comment: SPICE has an internal timestep control algorithm to determine when it should calculate data or not.  Setting the max parameter in `.tran` forces it to never go beyond that step size but it can go below if the algorithm decides to.  Downside is that it'll waste time calculating timesteps when nothing is changing and things are idle.  If you set the `tripdv`/`tripdt` parameters in the BV source you can avoid that inefficiency.  I can make all this an official answer if you think it's worth it.

Comment: I was trying to get something working using the level.3b opamp... No success, I'm going with the BV source with tripdv/tripdt solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how your Tline model works.
Seems also that the steps used are too large (I used 1 ps).
I don't have LH0063 in my database, so I took another opamp (AD8009).

Here is what I get.
TRAN Analysis

[image]

AC Analysis, with Group delay.

[image]